# No such comm target registered error in ipython

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython, jupyter, conda

When I start a python3 notebook in conda environment, I got such an error in terminal:

```
[I 21:59:46.185 NotebookApp] Creating new notebook in /Untitled Folder
[I 21:59:47.071 NotebookApp] Kernel started: a8c53aaf-8282-479d-b3ec-afb9433c30e6
[IPKernelApp] ERROR | No such comm target registered: ipython.widget
```

But if I start python2 instead, this error disappears. Do you know how I can deal with this problem?

Comment: isn't issue that folder name contains spaces? `untitled_folder` instead of `Untitled Folder`

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps all requirements are  satisfied in your python2 eńvironment but not in your python3 environment.

On my system I could make the error disappear by doing

`conda install ipywidgets`

and

`conda install widgetsnbextension`

On a non-Anaconda distribution, probably the same can be achieved by doing a

`pip3 install ipywidgets`

and

`pip3 install widgetsnbextension`

You may have to enable the extension using

`jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension`

Comment: Didn't work for me. 

Comment: did not work for me either!